# Testing reducer with createAsyncThunk rejected actions

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Currently, I am using v1.4.0 of @redux/toolkit and when I am testing a reducer using a rejected action created through a createAsync thunk with a custom rejectedWithValue. The action object can be created with a custom error payload like

```
asyncThunkAction.rejected(null, '', undefined, {
      message: 'error',
      errorCode: 500,
    });
```

with v1.5.0 you are no longer able to pass in the 4th error argument.

How are you able to test the behaviour of the slice with the rejected action containing the rejectedWith payload?

Answer (score 1):

You can now just pass it in as the first argument.

Please note that this is not a publicly documented API (the action creators are on there only for matching and accessing the error type) and we do not give guarantees for it's stability.

Comment: The first argument does not set the payload

Comment: Just re-checked: it does, but only if the first argument was created by calling `rejectWithValue`, otherwise it is handled as an error.
You are really dabbling with internals here. 
Honestly, I'd either create the action object by hand or actually use an actual asyncThunk with the same name that you manually reject.